# How do I copy Data from a excel in to word and keep its formatting

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have been trying to copy text from excel in to word, and retain the bold formatting on the text, but not the cell. When I try manually copy and paste over a cell the text is copied but not the cell itself. When I try repeat this using vb (as shown below) the cell is also copied over

```
With wrdDoc

    .Content.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Content.Font.Size = 11
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        Cells(1, 1).Copy
    End With
    .Content.InsertAfter "AddTableHere"
    .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="AddTableHere", ReplaceWith:="^c"


End With
```

Has anyone any suggestions on how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: There's a subtle error in your With Worksheets("Sheet1") block. The calls to Cells(1, 1).Select etc will still refer to the ActiveSheet which may not be Sheet1. I think you may have meant .Cells(1, 1).Select

Answer (score 1):

The `Selection` object in Word has a `PasteExcelTable` method which might fit the bill - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.pasteexceltable%28office.11%29.aspx) for details

Comment: Have tried that aswell, but pasting in to a document seems to overwrite all the contents of the document, even when i select to move the cursor to the end or the start. This macro will loop a number of times on the one document, so pasting doesnt seem to be an option for me